# NIC is going to destroyed and recreate in every run of terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

NIC is going to destroyed and recreate in every run of terraform, how to rectify this issue ?

Comment: Please add the terraform code along with the relevant output to the question.

Comment: **Hey @!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?**

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment it is working fine for me. Assuming you are creating Window Virtual Machine in that you are getting Nic recrete after every run/apply in terraform.

**terraform code**

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v--XXXX-XXX"
  #location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

***Result in first apply -- Its creating Nic for the VM***

[image]

***After second run/apply i am getting modifying the resources not recreting***

> Infrastructure is continuously evolving, and Terraform helps you
> manage that change. As you change Terraform configurations, Terraform
> builds an execution plan that only modifies what is necessary to reach
> your desired state.

[image]